# How to start "Here Drive+" navigation via app call with parameter (NFC tag)

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, here-api

I have Windows Phone 8.1 and just started to play around with nfc tags. I created a tag which calls the app "Here Drive+" which works fine, but i want to pass an address or coordinates to immediatly start the navigation to that location. Are there any supoorted parameters to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to find the HERE Launcher APIs available [here](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/change-history/archived-content/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/wp-uri-schemes-for-location-applications.html), but the documentation isn't available there anymore.

Comment: Sorry but i get 404 File not found, but i searched for launcher api, seems that is getting me closer to my target, thanks!

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/change-history/archived-content/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html

Comment: Oh, they killed the site just seconds after I posted the answer. LOL.

Comment: I think the page i need is "guidance-drive", but i still get a 404 error... I already contacted the administrator, but still no answer... -.-